# Converting PHP array to a single JSON object using js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have a php array(zero indexed) which I am sending to front end directly by echoing its json_encode format.

I want the JSON object to look like

```
{
    'A': null,
    'B': null,
    'C': null
}
```

But when I tried console.log i.e.,

```
console.log(<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>)
```

its printing js array

Also when I try print_r($array) in backend it prints

```
[array] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C

    )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the php array.

Comment: Question UPdated please see

Comment: Well that isn't a zero indexed array, it's an associative array. So I'm guessing what you actually have is a multidimensional zero indexed array which is filled with associative arrays, and you are outputting the whole thing.

Comment: Without some sort of transformation of the array on the backend, you'll never get what you are expecting. The code that creates the PHP array must be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code gives you the desired out put

```
$array = array
    (
        '0' => 'A',
        '1' => 'B',
        '2' => 'C'

    );
    $array = array_fill_keys($array, NULL);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Out Put:

```
{"A":null,"B":null,"C":null}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var data =<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

console.log(data);
//-->
</script>
```

Out Put:

```
 Object {A: null, B: null, C: null}
    A:null
    B:null
    C:null
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make your PHP array an array of ['A' => null, 'B' => null...]

Otherwise, your other option would be:

```
   $newArray = array_fill_keys($tags, null);
   json_encode($newArray);
```

This would take each array element in $tags, and set it as your index in newArray with a value of null.

Based on your code, you would have:

```
<?php $newArray = array_fill_keys($tags, null);
$json = json_encode($newArray); ?>
console.log(JSON.parse(<?= $json; ?>));
```

Comment: Thats showing                                                                                   
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (question:533)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: My mistake @pokemon, I misstyped based on reading your post. try my edit. You do not need "array_keys" - using my exact code, I was able to get what you are looking for.